# What is the dependency between the equivalence of consistence and satisfiability, and correctness and completeness theorems?

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, satisfiability

In Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic (2ed), in first order logic:

- It first proves [IV.6.2 the correctness of sequent calculus](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q&f=false) on p70 (if I am correct, the soundness of sequent calculus);
- It then proves [IV.7.5 a satisfiable set of formulas is also consistent](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false) on p73, based on the correctness of sequent calculus;

  > Proof.  Suppose    $\Phi$ is inconsistent.  Then for  a  suitable  $\phi$  both  $\Phi \vdash \phi$  and  $\Phi \vdash \neg \phi$;
  > hence,  by the theorem on the correctness of sequent calculus, $\Phi |= \phi$  and $\Phi |= \neg \phi$.  But  then $\Phi$  cannot be satisfiable.
- It then proves [V.(**) a consistent set of formulas is also satisfiable](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q&f=false) on p75:

  > Proof Sketch: we have to find a model for any consistent set   of formulas.  In Section 1 we  shall see that there is  a  natural way to do this if the set of formulas  is   negation complete and if it contains witnesses (Henkin's Theorem). Then we reduce the general case  to this one:  in  Section  2 for  at  most  countable  symbol  sets,  and in Section 3 for  arbitrary symbol sets.  Unless stated otherwise, we  refer to a fixed  symbol set S.
- It finally proves [V.(*) the completeness theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q&f=false) on p75:

  > We assume for $\Phi$  and $\phi$  that $\Phi |= \phi$,
  > but not $\Phi \vdash \phi$.  Then $\Phi \cup \{\neg \phi\}$  is  consistent but not satisfiable  (cf.  III.4.4
  > and IV.7.6(a)), a contradiction to (**).

Questions:

- Does it prove "a consistent set of formulas is also satisfiable" based on both the correntness of sequent calculus and "a satisfiable set of formulas is also consistent"?
- Does it prove the completeness theorem, based on all the other three?

I am not sure if the proofs in the book are the only ways.

- Can the equivalence of consistence and satisfiability (i.e. the second and the third) be proved without being based on the equivalence of consequential relation and provability (i.e. the correctness and completeness theorems, i.e. the first and the fourth)?
- Both consistence implying satisfiability and provability implying consequential relation go from syntax to semantics, while the other two (satisfiability implying consistence  and consequential relation implying provability) go from semantics to syntax. Can they be proved without being based on the other two? Similarly, can the other two be proved without being based on them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The "syntax-to-semantics vs. semantics-to-syntax" distinction is the wrong one, since it's really just about *phrasing* (the contrapositive of a "syntax-to-semantics" result is a "semantics-to-syntax" result). Rather,  we should think instead about the **positive content** of the relevant results: are they designed to yield instances of $\vdash$, or instances of $\models$?

We really have only two theorems here, although they appear in many different guises:

> Building instances of $\models$: "If $\Phi\vdash \varphi$ then $\Phi\models\varphi$." This is the **soundness** theorem. It's easily equivalent to the theorem that satisfiability implies consistency - note in particular that the latter is an instance of the contrapositive of the former (it says $\Phi\not\models\perp\implies\Phi\not\vdash\perp$).

> Building instances of $\vdash$: "If $\Phi\models\varphi$ then $\Phi\vdash\varphi$." This is the **completeness** theorem. As above, it's easily equivalent to the theorem that consistency implies satisfiability, via basically the same argument. Interestingly, the former is generally deduced as a consequence of the latter - it's easier to build structures than proofs, it turns out.

These two (classes of) results are completely independent of each other: consider the silly proof systems $\vdash_{arrogant}$ which lets you deduce anything from anything and $\vdash_{bashful}$ which doesn't let you deduce anything from anything. Trivially, $\vdash_{arrogant}$ is complete and $\vdash_{bashful}$ is sound for indeed any semantics whatsoever.

We can also find less trivial examples of one property holding without the other. If we take a very lax approach to deduction systems and allow them to be non-finitary and non-effective, then for example we have:

- The semantic entailment relation of Henkin semantics for second-order logic, thought of as a deduction system, is sound but not complete for the full semantics for second-order logic.
- The semantic entailment relation of full semantics for second-order logic, thought of as a deduction system, is complete but not sound for the Henkin semantics for second-order logic.

Basically, whenever we have one semantics which is strictly "narrower" than another, we'll get this phenomenon. I'll leave the search for better examples (e.g. effective and finitary) as an exercise.

---

It's worth noting that the soundness theorem is massively easier than the completeness theorem. The former is basically an exercise in induction on complexity, while the latter requires multiple fundamentally new ideas:

- Maximal consistent sets.
- Term structures.
- The witness property.

(Incidentally, the second of these is in my opinion the most significant.)

Comment: Thanks. What are definitions of "instances of ⊢, or instances of ⊨"? What do "⊥" and "Φ⊭⊥⟹Φ⊬⊥ " mean?

Comment: $\perp$ is the standard logical constant denoting falsity: being inconsistent is the same as proving $\perp$, and being unsatisfiable is the same as entailing $\perp$. If you prefer, replace $\perp$ with e.g. $\exists x(x\not=x)$. By "build instances of $\models$ (resp. $\vdash$)" I just mean "prove statements of the form "If A, then $\Phi\models\varphi$ (resp. $\Phi\vdash\varphi$)."

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand your answer. Could you be specific how you go from "If Φ⊢ then Φ⊨" to  "Φ⊭⊥⟹Φ⊬⊥" by  contrapositivity?

Comment: @Tim Well, the contrapositive of "If $\Phi\vdash\varphi$ then $\Phi\models\varphi$" is "If $\Phi\not\models\varphi$ then $\Phi\not\vdash\varphi$." Now just consider $\varphi\equiv\perp$. The more interesting part is showing that "If $\Phi\not\models\perp$ then $\Phi\not\vdash\perp$" implies the full principle "If $\Phi\not\models\varphi$ then $\Phi\not\vdash\varphi$."

Comment: Yes, that is what I am not sure about. I have not seen ⊥  in Ebbinghaus' book, though I have only read about first 80 pages.

Comment: @Tim Ah. Here's how that goes. Suppose we know that "For every $\Gamma$, if $\Gamma\not\models\perp$ then $\Gamma\not\vdash\perp$," and assume $\Phi\not\models\varphi$. Then we have $\Phi\cup\{\neg\varphi\}\not\models\perp$. Consequently $\Phi\cup\{\neg\varphi\}\not\vdash\perp$, and so $\Phi\not\vdash\varphi$. So the key thing to understand is how we can juggle between hypotheses and conclusions in instances of $\models$ or $\vdash$ (e.g. consider the deduction theorem).

Comment: I was wondering what mathematical logic books you like or recommend?

Comment: @Tim I am a huge huge fan of the Boolos/Burgess/Jeffrey book [*Computability and logic*](https://www.amazon.com/Computability-Logic-George-S-Boolos/dp/0521701465#reader_0521701465). Its one main drawback is the large amount of fluff at the beginning - it spends a lot of time on models of computation one might not be interested in - but its treatment of first-order logic is efficient and absolutely top-notch. As far as model theory goes, I would read (looking at the fifth edition) as follows (all numbers refer to chapters). First, 9-10 present the basic notions of first-order logic. (continued)

Comment: Next, 12-13 present the basic purely semantic theorems, namely Lowenheim-Skolem and Compactness. Chapter 14 brings syntax and semantics together, proving the soundness/completeness theorems; note that the proof system is introduced here, rather than early on in chapter 9, which is in my opinion helpful (since it means we don't have to deal with a ton of technical detail before we're ready to do something with it). The other big connection between syntax and semantics is of course the two *incompleteness* theorems, whose proofs are spread across 15-18 *(IIRC 11 is not actually necessary here)*.

Comment: Which edition of Computability and Logic do you like/recommend most: 5ed, 4ed, 3ed, 2ed, 1ed?